# Where are coaxial cables and twisted pair cables used relating to computer and device interconnection?

Tags: networking, coaxial, cable, twisted-pair

Is there some thing like a coaxial cable that can be used to connect same type of computers? And twisted pair cable can connect only computers (all types)?

The answer is yes it depends, but can anyone please explain the cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both coax and twisted pair can be used to connect many different types of devices including computers.

Whether a particular wire can be used to connect two devices depends on the hardware interfaces on those devices.

What form of communication can be done over such a connection depends on the software loaded on the device.

Coax and twisted pair are both commonly used for "Ethernet" network communication, but both can also support other protocols.

Comment: ?i know but still the question, is please explain the cases, lets say same type of hardware and software interface, which cable to use

Comment: Use the cable that fits the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You have horribly misspelt technical terms in your title, that is ludicrously sloppy. How are you to even search out the problem if you don't spell the terms correctly.

That aside.

I don't think what you've written in your question is the case. Did you get the idea from a book? if so, which?

ethernet many many years ago, before Cat5 cables(which are twisted pair), people used coaxial cable and some other metal bits and bobs since coaxial in ethernet wasn't used like cat5 with one device on each end and no devices in between, you had devices hooked onto it.

I would guess that you'd have printers and routers and so on, with coaxial interfaces also on the coaxial cable.  Not just computers.

Just like nowadays, computers routers and printers have RJ45 connectors.

(of course.. when I say computers have them.. I mean the motherboard or the ethernet card in them)

Comment: I'd say you don't have a lot of room to be so critical.

Comment: Do you mean I shouldn't because others could criticize me for my errors?  If I made errors then critically pointing them out is something I would want. I can defend not always capitalizing the first letter at the start of a sentence, my fingers get tired and it's not necessary, and i'm understood.  There -are- good reasons to spell technical terms correctly. You may not like my tone, but my best answer is there. You can reply to me in whatever tone you like. The important thing, is how good, and informative the answer is. And that we add or correct anything technically.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting Dennis, that there's some power structure where some people e.g. YOU dennis, can be "so critical", whereas others with lower rep values, don't have that right?   Because that is what you are suggesting. You do seem to be suggesting that I don't, but others (presumably YOU) do.  You suggest that you don't lack the "room" to be critical.

Comment: Dennis, I think if you make a comment that you can't defend in comments, (perhaps because arguing it or explaining it or defending it is not the place for it), then perhaps it's not the place to make the comment either.